# My Discord Python bot isn't sending emojis

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a bot which lists out the various custom emojis and what they mean. My code:

```
await message.channel.send(":up10: means the stock price has gone up more than 10% in the last 24 hours")
```

This is supposed to be showing an emoji in place of :up10: but all it does it print the literal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the emoji string to say  where 12345 is the ID of the emoji.

If you want to retrieve your emoji ID, send :up10: in chat and your discord client will change it to: <:up10:12345>

You need to send the whole thing they give you:

`await message.channel.send("<:up10:12345> is the emoji...")`

(Note that your ID will be much longer than 12345)

Comment: And to get the list of emoji with IDs, you can use [`discord.Guild.emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Guild.emojis).

Comment: @jirassimok is right you can do a for loop to list the ids of all the emojis in your server. Also whoever said this post is a duplicate is dead wrong. get_emoji is for ctx discord. The new API uses the in-text format that the original question-user is now using.